# AC water sensor for electrolysis

Tags: ac, sensor, water, electrolysis

I have 2 electrodes placed in a water bucket for electrolysis, electrode[A], and electrode[B].
I am supplying a positive DC voltage to electrode[A] and connecting electrode[B] to the ground and this polarity changes after half an hour and so on.
What I am trying to do is create another small piece of an electrode which I am calling water sensor here.

Whenever the water level in the water bucket touches the water sensor or whenever the water sensor is submerged inside the water, only then electrolysis happens otherwise there will not take place any electrolysis.
I have found many DC power supplied water sensors but there seems to be a problem of corroding. I am trying to avoid corrosion.

Comment: What is the material of the electrodes? Can you also add a diagram of the setup? Use the small [edit] button to add these details to the question. Note that electrolysis can itself be the cause of corrosion.

Comment: I know there are (1) ultrasonic sensor with stainless steel shells and can submerge in water, (2) tilt water sensor with wires, both are anti-corrosive, (3) Sensor stuck at the outside of the bucket wall.  PS - I am a poor hobbyist, so all above are cheap toys.

Comment: There you are: AliExpress Water Level Sensor Catalog (10,000 products!) - https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/water-level-sensor.html. Happy reading. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a sump pump style switch

You build a vertical rod with a float at the bottom.  The rod has "eye bolts" that let it move up and down but not sideways. The rod carries the motion quite far from the corrosive electrolyte.  Note the rod, channel and float can be plastic or fiberglass-epoxy. That linkage can then operate a switch.  If need be, it can carry a magnet near (or away from) a reed switch.

I like the magnet/reed switch option because you can drown that in epoxy to protect it from the electrolyte.

Do not attempt to switch AC power. Since you have DC power anyway, use low voltage DC power out to the switch, and have it operate a quality UL-Listed relay that switches mains power in a way supported by your local Electrical Codes.